# Execute commands from a file through putty in C#

Tags: c#

I have below code for run a putty with authentication from C#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ProcessStartInfo cmd = new ProcessStartInfo();
    cmd.FileName = "putty.exe";
    cmd.UseShellExecute = false;
    cmd.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    cmd.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    cmd.Arguments = "-ssh " + username + host+ " -pw " + upassword;
    using (Process process = Process.Start(cmd))
    {         
        process.WaitForExit();         
    }
}
```

The above code is launching putty and authenticating the user and password.
I want to execute some commands after launching the putty.  I used below code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ProcessStartInfo cmd = new ProcessStartInfo();
    cmd.FileName = "putty.exe";
    cmd.UseShellExecute = false;
    cmd.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    cmd.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    cmd.Arguments = "-ssh " + username + host+ " -pw " + upassword+ "-m "+path;;
    using (Process process = Process.Start(cmd))
    {         
        process.WaitForExit();         
    }
}
```

The path variable contains the location of the file and file contain below text in it

```
ssh webhostname
```

While executing the above code, putty is launched but during authentication putty terminated with message "Unauthorized access to this machine is prohibited"

Is there anyway we can run the commands in putty from a file?

Comment: In your `cmd.Arguments` line, should there be an `@` between `username` and  `host` ?

Comment: Try adding a manifest file to your solution with requireAdministrator for execution level:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator

Comment: @Awakening Byte  I am handling @ symbol when I am passing the hostname. I appended the @ symbol in hostname variable.